# Testimonials shortcode also showing in my site? How to avoid this issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hey Guys Extremely sorry for the silly question because I am newbie to wordpress. I just wanted to show user testimonials.

For that I Installed [Easy Testimonials](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-testimonials/) Plugin.
Then I creates a new page called **Testimonials**. In that I give the below shortcode

```
[testimonials theme="default_style" paginate="all" count="5" orderby="date" order="ASC" show_title="0" use_excerpt="0" show_thumbs="1" show_date="1" show_other="1" hide_view_more="1" output_schema_markup="1" show_rating="stars"]
```

Upto now all are working fine, But in my site its showing that shortcode that I have given in the testimonial page.
[image]

My admin panel
[image]

This is my page.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages and that other
 * 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a different template.
 *
 * @package OceanWP WordPress theme
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'ocean_before_content_wrap' ); ?>

    <div id="content-wrap" class="container clr">

        <?php do_action( 'ocean_before_primary' ); ?>

        <div id="primary" class="content-area clr">

            <?php do_action( 'ocean_before_content' ); ?>

            <div id="content" class="site-content clr">

                <?php do_action( 'ocean_before_content_inner' ); ?>

                <?php
                // Elementor `single` location
                if ( ! function_exists( 'elementor_theme_do_location' ) || ! elementor_theme_do_location( 'single' ) ) {

                    // Start loop
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                        get_template_part( 'partials/page/layout' );

                    endwhile;

                } ?>

                <?php do_action( 'ocean_after_content_inner' ); ?>

            </div><!-- #content -->

            <?php do_action( 'ocean_after_content' ); ?>

        </div><!-- #primary -->

        <?php do_action( 'ocean_after_primary' ); ?>

        <?php do_action( 'ocean_display_sidebar' ); ?>

    </div><!-- #content-wrap -->

    <?php do_action( 'ocean_after_content_wrap' ); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: are you using the_content() to display it? in your template

Comment: bro where I have to check that. I think page.php right???

Comment: the place where you are calling testimonials, might be page.php

Comment: no bro. I didnt use the_content() to display.

Comment: please post some code, how you are displaying

Comment: I just edit my question bro please have a look

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to go to admin panel **Testimonials->All Testimonials** select edit testimonial  and check description content there

Comment: there is no all testmonials.... there is 1.testimonials 2.add new testmonial 
3.testmonial category

Comment: ok then select your testimonial which is in the screenshot you shred from testimonials and edit and check description

Comment: Make sure you haven't pasted the shortcode anywhere in your testimonial.

Comment: If you had pasted it in your testimonial priviously by mistake and then removed it later it will still show on your page. So generate your shortcode again and past on your page where you want to display testimonial.

Comment: I just give the shortcode in the content of my testmonial page and I didnt pass the short code

Answer (score 0):

in your page.php put below code anywhere and check it working or not

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[testimonials theme="default_style" paginate="all" count="5" orderby="date" order="ASC" show_title="0" use_excerpt="0" show_thumbs="1" show_date="1" show_other="1" hide_view_more="1" output_schema_markup="1" show_rating="stars"]'); ?>
```